# apply function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

When i run the following

```
import pandas as pd


def my_func(E, I):

    return E * I


d = {'E': [1, 1], 'I': [2, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['S'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x['E'], x['I']),axis=1).map(lambda x: x[0])
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:\GSY\scipt.py", line 14, in <module>
    df['S'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x['E'], x['I']),axis=1).map(lambda x: x[0])
  File "C:\Users\gsy.LSH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3630, in map
    new_values = super()._map_values(arg, na_action=na_action)
  File "C:\Users\gsy.LSH\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py", line 1145, in _map_values
    new_values = map_f(values, mapper)
  File "pandas\_libs\lib.pyx", line 2329, in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer
  File "U:\GSY\script.py", line 14, in <lambda>
    df['S'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x['E'], x['I']),axis=1).map(lambda x: x[0])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I 'm 100% sure that this was working in the past as i have used it extensively.
Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: why `apply` and `map`? What are you trying to do here? This should never work, unless you have a different function.

Comment: I’d assume you added the .map part by mistake?

Comment: I don't understand the separate function here. Why not just do `df.E * df.I`?

Comment: i want to call a function which takes some arguments. The multiplication is just for the sake of simplicity for this example. When i had a function that returns more than one values i used the following:

Comment: df['type'] = df.apply(lambda x: stiffener_parameters(x['Member'], x['t_c_s'], x['b_eff'], x['s']),axis=1).map(lambda x: x[0])

Comment: df['h_w'] = df.apply(lambda x: stiffener_parameters(x['Member'], x['t_c_s'], x['b_eff'], x['s']),axis=1).map(lambda x: x[1])

Comment: df['t_w'] = df.apply(lambda x: stiffener_parameters(x['Member'], x['t_c_s'], x['b_eff'], x['s']),axis=1).map(lambda x: x[2])

Comment: and so on until i get all the returned values in my dataframe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drop the last map at the end.  The function is returning a list and your last map function is trying to take the first element of a list.

```
import pandas as pd

def my_func(E, I):
    return E * I

d = {'E': [1, 1], 'I': [2, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['S'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x['E'], x['I']),axis=1)
```

Alternatively but based on the comments here you could return the value from my_func as a list:

```
import pandas as pd

def my_func(E, I):
    return [E * I]

d = {'E': [1, 1], 'I': [2, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['S'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_func(x['E'], x['I']),axis=1).map(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: yes you are right!!! i was getting this error because of the .map function because i was using it when multiple values were being return from my function. I got it now! Thanks